# Node.js MySQL: Select-statement depending on query string?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

I'm building an auction house. I'm using the nodejs-mysql package and I have this nodejs `server.js`-code for the main page, **where multiple auctions are displayed**:

```
// loop
var pollingLoop = function() {
  // Doing the database query
var query = connection.query('SELECT a.`id`,a.`product_id`,a.`price`,a.`random`,a.`price_end`,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),a.`date_end`) AS duration,p.`price_retail` FROM `auctions` AS a LEFT JOIN `products` AS p ON p.`id` = a.`product_id` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),a.`date_end`) > "-1" ORDER BY `duration` DESC,`id` DESC'),
    auctions = [];
```

1. How can I accomplish that this query is changed when a `$_GET['id']` is available to another `SELECT`-statement with a `WHERE`-condition? Because I want to add `WHERE auction='$_GET['id']'` **for a single auction** then (but server-side).
2. Is there a way to make it more readable? Because when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the `SELECT`-statement won't work at all. This is how it looks on the nodejs-server-file `server.js`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37fDl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to break up a Javascript string into multiple lines: Backslashing and string concatenation.

Delimiting with backslashes

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\
consectetur adipisicing elit,\
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
```

Delimiting with string concatenation

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
         + "consectetur adipisicing elit,"
         + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"
         + "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
```

You need to build your query dinamically. Something like this.

```
var query = 'SELECT \
    a.`id`, \
    a.`product_id`, \
    a.`price`, \
    a.`random`, \
    a.`price_end`, \
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, \
        NOW(), \
        a.`date_end`) AS duration, \
    p.`price_retail` \
FROM \
    `auctions` AS a \
        LEFT JOIN \
    `products` AS p ON p.`id` = a.`product_id`';

var where = '';
if (condition) {
   where = 'WHERE \
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, \
        NOW(), \
        a.`date_end`) > - 1';
} else {
   where = "auction='$_GET['id']'";
}

var order = ' ORDER BY `duration` DESC , `id` DESC';
query = query + where + order 
var res = connection.query(query), auctions = [];
```

p.s.
This is just an idea. For example, you can use `var where = array()` and fill it  with conditions. Then, just loop over array and create query joining conditions by `AND`.

upd:

If you don't use *express* module, you can find GET parameters using url module.

```
var query = require('url').parse(req.url,true).query;

var id = query.id;
var some_par = query.some_par;

For url: /path/filename?id=123&some_par=456
```

Then you can build query with `id` variable.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm trying just to get the id, but my result is "undefined" than. With that code: `var qry = require('url').parse(socket.handshake.url); var qry_id = qry.id;`

Comment: Don't forget TRUE - .parse(socket.handshake.url, true);

What you get console.log(qry) ?

Comment: Yes, I already added "true". It says [object Object] then. But if I type `console.log(qry.path)` the whole url shows. But how can I just get a specific query string like id? And why is he showing the socket.io url and not the url of my localhost?

Comment: http://localhost:3001/?id=456789 - var qry = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query; - 
console.log(qry.id); - this works for me fine.

Comment: I just found out the issue. It's about the folder. In `server.js` it's defined as `http.listen(1337)`. But I'm not testing on `http://localhost:1337`. I testing on `http://localhost/customname/`. So that's why I dont get an id. But how can I change it to the customname folder that for example `http://localhost/customname/?id=1234` would work too?

Comment: Thank you for all your patience. I looked for the issue all the time and I guess it's about **xampp and nodejs combined**. The apache server of xampp runs on port 80 and nodejs as defined on port 1337. So now I cant see my website when I open localhost:1337, because I have to use the port 80 to see my apache files. That's the problem. Isn't there a way to tell socket.io or the node.js-server to get/parse the url of the specific port 80?

Comment: You cant bind more then one process to listen to specific posrt. But you can configure redirect from one server to another. You must configure xampp in such way, that all connections to port 80 that doesn't ask for static files will redirected to port 1337. Google for xampp as proxy to nodejs, something like this. This is normal practice to do that.